# Weex - why can not I start the project

Tags: npm, vue.js, weex

I have a problem with weex. I wanted to start to learn to write a Vue app using weex, but I have a problem because I can not download the package. I have an empty folder and enter the command from the npm documentation install weex-toolkit -g, but it will give me such an error.

Image error:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/424284796068429824/431948032897187841/unknown.png

Answer (score 0):

The error is from an npm dependency, `fsevents`, not weex per-se.

Have you tried on a different platform, or see if the toolkit got installed anyway?